# -[UIWebView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:] affects all instances

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

If I have a `UIWebView` with `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = YES`, then later in my app create a new `UIWebView` and set `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO` on it, it also changes the value of that property on the first instance.

e.g. I have a `UIWebView` and then present a second `UIWebView` modally (for an ad), changing `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` on the modal webView affects the presenting `UIWebView`.

Any ideas why this is? Are `UIWebViews` all backed by a single instance?

Link to sample project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1790795/AutoPlayRadar.zip).

Comment: A web view should be a distinct object -- can you confirm that you're dealing with two separate instances? One other potential pitfall is placing a web view into a scroll view. If the second web view is being inserted _into_ the first, I would expect weird stuff.

Comment: @AaronVegh yeah, they're two instances. I present the second one modally, and if I po them they are different. I'll update my question to link to a sample project.

Comment: Looking at the code and the docs, it feels like it might be an HTML5 issue. Consider that the docs specifically refer to the capability of both media playback requiring user action refer to HTML5 video. Your HTML code doesn't use the HTML5 <video> element to do the playback; you can't playback inline using the iframe method, for example. I'd suggest playing with that and see if it helps.

Comment: Did you run the sample app? Change a property on one instance changes the property on the second instance... if mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = YES, the video doesn't auto play.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. Did you file a radar @Senior?

I'm using the Google ADMob SDK, which sets mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to NO on its own webviews. This essentially enables autoplay on all my own webviews, which I do not want!

I've also discovered that there is some persistence to this. The value of mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction will persist across app launches. Even though the default value should be YES, it can be NO in newly created instances of UIWebView when it has been set in previous app launches.

Comment: @acorscadden yup, feel free to dupe radar://17574220

Comment: duplicate filed https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5014091588435968

Answer (score 0):

not sure your app purpose, just try this way:

```
- (IBAction)unwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
    [self TS_updateLabel];

        [[self webView] setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:YES];

        [self TS_reloadWebView];
}
```

....

in method `TS_reloadWebView`

```
 if (self.webView.isLoading) {
        [self.webView stopLoading];

    }
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

I guess it also is `UIWebView` bug .... but now this way maybe can solve your problem.